# When building new system and planning to VM the old one is there any disadvantage to changing CPU brands

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

Current system is Windows 7 x64 Ultimate with Intel i5-2500 on an ASUS mITX board, and I've been considering an AMD Ryzen CPU on an ASRock ATX board for a new system build.

I will need to run the Windows 7 x64 image as a VM for quite a while on the new machine. Do I complicate things for myself in any way by switching from Intel to AMD in this scenario?

Comment: Even if you stick with an Intel CPU you will have to activate your installation due to it being substantially different hardware.  Even if you run it within a VM the hardware will be significantly different and will require you to activate the installation again.  Using an AMD or Intel CPU won't make any difference at all.

Comment: Thanks, that's good. How does Windows know it is on a different machine when it's opened as a VM? Do CPUs report a unique ID of some kind?

Comment: And can I just pop the old system drive into the new machine and point to it as the image when setting up the VM (and then reactivate license)?

Comment: "How does Windows know it is on a different machine when it's opened as a VM?" - The hardware will be different, it will be that of the VM, which at the very least will be identified as the hardware of the host.

Comment: "can I just pop the old system drive into the new machine and point to it as the image when setting up the VM (and then reactivate license)?" - Windows can be moved to another machine, I have only ever successfully achieved it using third-party imaging software, Windows does not like encountering  entirely different hardware randomly.  Your installation likely will not boot if you try that.